# Changing Font Size in Eclipse Package Explorer and Search

Tags: eclipse

I am running Eclipse Neon on a Mac, with the EGit plugin. 
I would like to make the font size bigger in IDE tree structures.

I tried removing the smallFonts line from the eclipse.ini, and setting the font-size for every css class that I could find (MPart, Tree, etc...) in the Mac css file, as suggested in other answers.  The font size changes for only some of the nodes in the tree.  Any node with an edited file in one of it's children (with a '>' symbol) still appears with a small font.

I installed CSS Spy to try and figure out the CSS class, but I don't see anything in there that I haven't set a font-size for.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that ever worked for me was TinkerTool https://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html.

I increased all the font sizes, not sure which one Eclipse actually uses though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I only wanted to increase the Eclipse font sizes and wanted to leave them as is everywhere else, so I don't think that TinkerTool will work for me (although it does look like an interesting tool).

Comment: Answering my own question — "Help tags" is the size I can change in TinkerTool to affect the Eclipse Project Explorer.